# Extract values from a certain layer in a stack based on pixel value of another raster

Tags: r, extract, raster, r-raster

Suppose I have a raster layer `r0` that the values range from `1: nlayers s`. I need to extract values from the bands `s` that matches the  pixel values from layer `r0`.
**For example, if a pixel value in `r0` is `2` I want the value of the exact same pixel from `band 2` in stacked layers `s`** and so forth. So the final output would be only one layer representing the values from layer `s` based on layer `r0`. I hope I could explain the problem properly.

```
library(raster)

r <- raster(nrow=5, ncol=5)
r0 <- setValues(r, round(runif(25,min = 1, max = 10)), 0)




r1 <- setValues(r, runif(ncell(r)))
r2 <- setValues(r, runif(ncell(r)))
r3 <- setValues(r, runif(ncell(r)))
r4 <- setValues(r, runif(ncell(r)))
r5 <- setValues(r, runif(ncell(r)))
r6 <- setValues(r, runif(ncell(r)))
r7 <- setValues(r, runif(ncell(r)))
r8 <- setValues(r, runif(ncell(r)))
r9 <- setValues(r, runif(ncell(r)))
r10 <- setValues(r, runif(ncell(r)))


s <- stack(r1, r2, r3, r4,r5, r6,r7,r8,r9,r10)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `terra::selectRange`

example data

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(ncols=10, nrows=10)
values(r) <- 1
s <- c(r, r+2, r+5)
s <- c(s, s)
set.seed(1)
values(r) <- sample(3, ncell(r), replace=TRUE)
```

Solution

```
x <- selectRange(s, r)
```

Comment: I didn't know that terra requires specific type of files, separate from the raster package. Does it allow to add a function to it? For example, extract the values from + and - 5 layers and take the mean?